# Need a javascript function to identify the which textbox used while clicking save button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, client-side-validation

I have 3 textboxes in 3 tabs of same ASP.net page and corresponding 3 javascript functions of same functionality. Presently I am using 3 different functions for three textboxes. I need only a single javascript function instead of three. Please help me

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" ValidationonGroup="abcd"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ID1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="abcd" ControlToValidate="textBox1" ErrorMessage="message" ClientValidationFunction="fname"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Javascript functon

```
function fname(sender, args) {
 var x = document.getElementById('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>').value;
 if (some condition) { 
args.IsValid = false; 
} else { 
args.IsValid = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be checking which textbox value != "" and execute the send based on this

eg your onClick handler could contain this.

```
if(document.getElementById('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>').value != ""){ 
do this
} else if (document.getElementById('<%=txtBox2.ClientID%>').value != ""){ 
do this
} else {
do this
}
```

Comment: No, if this need to work you have to make sure only 1 box is filled, which could be done when the user changes tab.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make one function that receives text box ID and call it from other 3:

```
function fname(textBoxID, sender, args) {
  var x = document.getElementById(textBoxID).value;
  if (some condition) { 
    args.IsValid = false; 
  } else { 
  args.IsValid = true;
  }
}
```

When you call it for first text box, just pass '<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>' as first parameter. Same way, pass '<%=txtBox2.ClientID%>' for second text box...

There is another solution, you can find it more in detail here: [Passing value from CustomValidator](http://forums.asp.net/t/1296600.aspx?Passing%20value%20from%20CustomValidator%20to%20ClientValidationFunction)

In short it goes like this: use sender.id to get the id of the CustomValidator. Then so long as the validator's id is the id of the TextBox with a prefix of 'Validator_', I can use a javascript replace to get rid of the 'Validator_', therefore finding out the TextBox Id.

Comment: Nice suggestions . Please help me how to pass the textBoxId like that. In the html code I am adding only the function name like ClientValidationFunction="fname".
Please explain me how to pass textBoxId like that

Comment: for first text box call function called fname1: (sender, args) and from it call fname('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>', sender, args);  for second text box call function fname2, and from it fname('<%=txtBox2.ClientID%>', sender, args) etc...

Comment: I have edited my answer. There is nice solution to this problem, see link in edited answer.